# Inserting HTML web page inside SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Usually we are embedding SWF in HTML, but is it possible to embed an HTML inside SWF? Say stackoverflow.com can be seen inside SWF?

I've heard HTML wrapper, but how should one code in actionscript to make it possible?

Answer (score 1):

With AIR it is possible to have HTML content running inside a WebView component capable of viewing HTML content with active JavaScript code and correct representation of CSS style sheets.

If you wish to do it in a Flash Player, not AIR, you could do this with the help of IFrame in Flex http://www.deitte.com/archives/2006/08/finally%5Fupdated.htm